# parallel execution in shell scripting hangs

Tags: shell, unix

My requirement is to run multiple shell scripts at a time.
After searching on Google could conclude that I can use "&" at the end of filename while triggering the run like:

```
sh file.sh &
```

the thing is I have for loop which generates the values and gives runtime parameters for the shell script:

sample code:

```
declare -a arr=("1" "2")

for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};++i));
do
sh fileto_run.sh ${arr[i]}
done
```

this successfully triggers the fileto_run.sh in parallel but it hangs there itself.. imagine I have echo statement in the script then the following is how the code hangs:

```
-bash-x.x$ 1
2
```

until I use ctrl+c the code execution wont exit.
I thought of using a break statement but that breaks the loop.

Am I doing wrong anywhere?
Please do correct me.

Comment: Where is the `&` at the end of script line inside the `for loop` ?

Comment: it helps in executing multiple script in parallel.